# Less than 6 months bank statement in UK visitor visa?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, money, proof-provenance-of-funds

I've read many posts on TSE explaining the importance of bank statements and why they are necessary but has anyone applied for a UK standard visitor visa with only 3-5 months of perfect cash flow showing bank statements during their first visa application from India or Pakistan, if so what was the outcome? I'm planning to upload 3-4 months of bank statements with my application along with other appropriate assets and socio-economic ties documents.

Comment: I've recently had a 10 year standard visitor visa approved with only 3 months of bank statements included with my application. But this was not my 1st UK visa, and I applied from the USA.

Comment: You'll make the officer who looks at your application suspicious which is seldom a good thing.

Comment: Thanks brhans and henrik.

Comment: There is no specific requirement for 6 months’ worth of bank statements https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk If the rest of your application is solid (credible reason for the visit, previous travel history, ties to home country etc), it may not matter. But if it’s your first application, why skimp and risk a refusal?